# Did Cameron cheat on her husband?

Tags: house

In *House MD* S1E7 "Fidelity", the script seems to be alluding to the fact that Cameron cheated on her husband:

- She unprofessionally and IMHO immorally calls the cheated-on husband a terrible person
- She's TOTALLY in the bag rooting for the cheating wife, comforting her and attacking the husband for leaving her and lecturing him about "love"
- House calls her out that her reaction is not in line with the "official" story she gave him (that her husband died at 6 months from cancer).

*All together, this seems to be hinting at the fact that Cameron has cheated on her dying husband.*

My question is, is there **more canonical information** confirming or denying that theory? Something from script, actors, crew, producers, etc...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, upon watching the series further, found the answer: ***she cheated emotionally but not physically, by her own admission.***

Specifically, in Season 2, Episode 6 "Spin", in one of the final scenes, Wilson and Cameron discuss cheating (original context being a patient who is a cyclist, cheating at cycling):

> *Cameron*: "He got away with it."
>
> *Wilson*: "Uhmmmmm, he cheated and won a game. Life's more complicated than who gets to the finish line first."
>
> *Cameron:* **I fell in love with my husband's best friend. Near the end** I
> was at the hospital every day, and Joe would come by after work. We'd
> go for walks and try to talk each other through it. We kind of clung
> on to each other.
>
> *Wilson:* ... What happened to you, how can anyone go through
> that alone? You can't control your emotions.
>
> *Cameron*: No. Just your actions.
>
> *Wilson*: **You didn't do it, did you? You didn't sleep with him.**
>
> *Cameron*: **I couldn't have lived with myself.**